# Is there a name for the following transhumanist doctrine: "the most important thing to do with one's life is to try to avoid death"?

Tags: reference-request, terminology, death

[Disclaimer: I don't have any formal training in philosophy and I'm just curious, so I hope this question is in scope.]

I'm interested in whether there is an established name for a simple (admittedly simplistic) doctrine about death, or existing discussion of the idea. For simplicity I'll phrase it in terms of a fictional character, Bob:

> Bob assumes that it is technologically possible in principle to achieve indefinite [life extension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Life_extension), i.e., that there is a chance that his biological lifespan (in good health) can be extended indefinitely with the right technology and means, and with enough luck. (E.g., via [mind uploading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mind_uploading), [anti-aging research](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anti-aging_movement#Mass_movement), [organ culture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Organ_culture), the [singularity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Technological_singularity), etc.) Bob does not want to die, and believes that the most important thing to do with his life is then to try to find a way to extend his lifespan. So he wants to live his life in the way that maximizes his chances towards this goal.
>
> The logistics of this may take different forms: directly working on relevant research, or political advocacy for the importance of such research, or earning enough money to finance it, and/or also earning enough money to be wealthy enough to personally benefit from the outcomes if they materialize. And, of course, staying alive in the meantime, i.e., avoiding risk and preventable death causes.

**Is there an established name for Bob's belief?** Has such a position been discussed, e.g., in philosophical work?

Another way to present this doctrine would be via a thought experiment. Suppose a mad scientist has developed a lethal poison and administered it to you. Its effect is certain death within some fixed number *N* of days (say, *N*=30). The scientist then disappears, leaving you only with the chemical formula of this new poison, for which there is no cure currently known to science. Do you try to find a way to save yourself, e.g., by trying to get in touch with people who may be able to invent a remedy? Or do you just give up and enjoy the time you have left? If you do try to save yourself, what changes if we replace the mad scientist by death and *N* by some upper bound on your remaining lifespan?

Relevant things I have found about this doctrine:

- Bob's view is clearly [transhumanist](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transhumanism), and it is also [individualist](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Individualism), or arguably falls into [rational egoism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_egoism), but it is more specific.
- The [anti-aging movement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anti-aging_movement) and concepts like the [pro-aging trance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pro-aging_trance) are similar but they argue for a *social* imperative to cure aging collectively. By contrast Bob's doctrine is a purely individual choice.
- Bob's doctrine looks like applying the idea of [longtermism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longtermism) to one's own life, specifically avoiding [existential risks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_catastrophic_risk): on a personal level, achieving unlimited life extension means avoiding the obvious existential threat, so may yield a huge payoff even if the probability of success is low. Of course [Pascal's mugging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal%27s_mugging) is also relevant to Bob.
- Of course Bob very much wants to avoid death, so his beliefs are related to [death anxiety](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Death_anxiety); but his doctrine goes further and pushes him, in a sense, to do something about it. By the way, it doesn't mean that the only thing that Bob will ever care about is extending his lifespan, just that this question is incomparably more important. Bob might hope that he eventually gets to a state where he is confident that his existence will continue indefinitely, at which point he may find some other hobbies to fill his copious free time.
- One can guess that many anti-aging proponents may also find a personal motivation in trying to extend their own life. A notable example is [Ray Kurzweil's attempts to extend his own lifespan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ray_Kurzweil#Health_and_aging). But somehow I didn't find an explicit discussion of the concept that one would try to cure aging (not just survive) because one believes that it is subjectively the most important thing to do. The closest view I found is that expressed in [the first answer of this interview](https://www.liebertpub.com/doi/epub/10.1089/rej.2015.1758) but it is not stated there as a general principle.

Comment: Along the linguistic (not quite semantic, though) lines of the word "antinatalism," so: **antimortalism**.

Comment: Notable proponents of this position (as opposed to the desire to postpone death for everyone) include Count Dracula and Lord Voldemort, and there's precedent for naming behavioral disorders after fictional characters (narcissism, Oedipus complex). I vote for voldemortism.